# Python & Tkinter Structure Issue

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, global

```
import Tkinter as tk   # python
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Frame, Button, Style


TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 14, "bold")

letter = ""

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.controller = controller
        #label = tk.Label(self, text="HOME", font=TITLE_FONT)
        #label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)


        def exeB(val):
            global letter
            letter = val
            print("Here it is: " + letter)
            controller.show_frame("PageTwo")   

        Style().configure("TButton", padding=(0, 5, 0, 5),#0505 
            font='serif 10')

        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(4, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(5, pad=3)

        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=3)

        t = tk.Button(self, text="T", height="4", width="6", command=lambda: exeB("T"))
        t.grid(row=3, column=4)

        self.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="PageOne", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="<",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text= letter, font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        choices = tk.Listbox(self, height="10", width="25")
        choices.insert(1, letter)
        choices.insert(2, "CPP")
        choices.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", pady=10)
        print("found2 " + letter)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="<",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.geometry('480x320')
    app.mainloop()
```

I wrote the above code using a couple different tutorials and examples with the purpose of letting the user select a letter but pushing on a button, and then another frame would pop up with a listbox that had that letter as an option to choose from.

However, my global variable "letter" is not being modified when I click the "T" button and the exeB() function runs. But don't write me off yet :-). I searched and found that you have to make it global otherwise changes are disregarded when the function finishes. So I added the line `global letter` in my function.

To my dismay this did not change a thing! What am I doing wrong? I am used to coding in C++ and GUIs in general are very hard for me. I couldn't find a question that related to mine, that solved it.

Comment: You have `letter` defined both in the global scope and as a class variable in `SampleApp`, is this intended? I assume that your global variable is working okay, but you're accidently getting the value of the class variable.

Comment: Apologies, that was not there when I was testing code. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function to update all places where `letter` is used and then call that whenever you show the frame in which `letter` is used.

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        # made this an instance variable since we will need it later
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text= letter, font=TITLE_FONT)
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        # made this an instance variable since we will need it later
        self.choices = tk.Listbox(self, height="10", width="25")
        self.choices.insert(0, letter)
        self.choices.insert(1, "CPP")
        self.choices.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", pady=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="<",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

    # new method to update the label and choice list
    def update(self):
        self.label.text = letter
        self.choices.delete(0)
        self.choices.insert(0, letter)
```

Now, whenever we want to show this page, we need to make sure we update it first.

```
def show_frame(self, page_name):
    '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
    frame = self.frames[page_name]

    # tries to find and call an update method on the frame
    update_method =  getattr(frame, 'update', None)
    if callable(update_method):
        update_method()

    frame.tkraise()
```

Comment: Im sorry but I am new to python and GUI coding...where exactly would I put that function? In the startpage class? How would I make the function give me the desired result?

Comment: Since it didn't matter I changed it to a char but declaring letter = ' ' and passing it exeB('T'). However, still no luck.

Comment: Wow, so I found out there is no such thing as char in python. Do you think it would make more since to write this in C with GTK?

Comment: @NULL It seems like this is a structural issue rather than a Python issue. For example, a `char` is just a string of length 1. I've updated my answer with working code.

Comment: Ok thats very helpful!